# How to make files with specific HEX pattern in Bash?

Tags: bash, dd

I'm trying to make many files (4KB~10MB) with specific 4-byte HEX pattern in Bash.

For example:

```
0000000: 1234 5678 1234 5678 1234 5678 1234 5678 ....
```

So I made zero pattern data using `dd` and converted it to specific 4-byte HEX pattern like below

```bash
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1k count=10 | tr "\000" $'\x12345678' > File.bin
```

But it returns only the first 1 byte of the given HEX pattern.

```
0000000 : 1212 1212 1212 1212 1212 1212 1212 1212 ....
```

Which point should I fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use perl

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero bs=1k count=10 | perl -0777 -pe "s/\x00{4}/\x12\x34\x56\x78/g" > file.bin

$ xxd file.bin 

0000000: 1234 5678 1234 5678 1234 5678 1234 5678  .4Vx.4Vx.4Vx.4Vx
0000010: 1234 5678 1234 5678 1234 5678 1234 5678  .4Vx.4Vx.4Vx.4Vx
...
```

Answer (score 1):

On little endian

```
printf '\x34\x12\x78\x56%.0s' {1..10} > File.bin
```

Comment: Thanks, but any idea which can enhance performance? I need to make thousands of MB files

Comment: sorry that wasn't clear, @123 's answer could be correct then.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use [`yes`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/yes.1.html)

```
yes $'\x12\x34\x56\x78' | tr -d '\n' | head -c 10240
```

If you have [GNU head](https://manual) you can also specify the size suffix like 4MB, 10M... directly

```
$ yes $'\x12\x34\x56\x78' | tr -d '\n' | head -c 4kB | hexdump -C
00000000  12 34 56 78 12 34 56 78  12 34 56 78 12 34 56 78  |.4Vx.4Vx.4Vx.4Vx|
*
00000fa0
```

---

You can also use [`jot`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/1/jot/). For example the below command will generate a 4K output

```
jot -s "" -b $'\x12\x34\x56\x78' 4096
```

---

Performance comparison: among the current solutions `yes` + GNU `tr` is the fastest one and can achieve hundreds of MBs per second

On Linux:

```
$ time dd if=/dev/zero bs=300M count=1 2>/dev/null | perl -0777 -pe "s/\x00{4}/\x12\x34\x56\x78/g" >/dev/null

real    0m4.714s
user    0m4.416s
sys 0m0.395s
$ time jot -s "" -b $'\x12\x34\x56\x78' $((300*1024*1024)) >/dev/null

real    0m13.486s
user    0m13.330s
sys 0m0.152s
$ time yes $'\x12\x34\x56\x78' | tr -d '\n' | head -c 300M >/dev/null

real    0m0.373s
user    0m0.227s
sys 0m0.556s
```

On macOS I've tried both BSD tools and GNU tools (prefixed with `g`), and you can see that BSD tools are quite terrible

```
$ time yes $'\x12\x34\x56\x78' | tr -d '\n' | ghead -c 300M >/dev/null
yes $'\x12\x34\x56\x78'  0.03s user 0.20s system 0% cpu 27.792 total
tr -d '\n'  27.71s user 0.07s system 99% cpu 27.791 total
ghead -c 300M > /dev/null  0.16s user 0.24s system 1% cpu 27.788 total

$ time gyes $'\x12\x34\x56\x78' | tr -d '\n' | ghead -c 300M >/dev/null
gyes $'\x12\x34\x56\x78'  0.15s user 0.30s system 1% cpu 27.997 total
tr -d '\n'  27.92s user 0.07s system 99% cpu 27.995 total
ghead -c 300M > /dev/null  0.16s user 0.25s system 1% cpu 27.992 total

$ time yes $'\x12\x34\x56\x78' | gtr -d '\n' | ghead -c 300M >/dev/null
yes $'\x12\x34\x56\x78'  0.02s user 0.46s system 46% cpu 1.013 total
gtr -d '\n'  0.51s user 0.42s system 92% cpu 1.012 total
ghead -c 300M > /dev/null  0.14s user 0.17s system 30% cpu 1.011 total

$ time gyes $'\x12\x34\x56\x78' | gtr -d '\n' | ghead -c 300M >/dev/null
gyes $'\x12\x34\x56\x78'  0.13s user 0.44s system 66% cpu 0.855 total
gtr -d '\n'  0.48s user 0.33s system 95% cpu 0.854 total
ghead -c 300M > /dev/null  0.13s user 0.16s system 34% cpu 0.852 total

$ time jot -s "" -b $'\x12\x34\x56\x78' $((300*1024*1024)) >/dev/null
jot -s "" -b $'\x12\x34\x56\x78' $((300*1024*1024)) > /dev/null  38.22s user 0.04s system 99% cpu 38.270 total

$ time dd if=/dev/zero bs=300M count=1 2>/dev/null | perl -0777 -pe "s/\x00{4}/\x12\x34\x56\x78/g" >/dev/null
dd if=/dev/zero bs=300M count=1 2> /dev/null  0.00s user 0.20s system 51% cpu 0.392 total
perl -0777 -pe "s/\x00{4}/\x12\x34\x56\x78/g" > /dev/null  4.26s user 0.34s system 96% cpu 4.739 total
```